# Django's send_mail messages get grouped into a gmail converation

Tags: python, django, email, python-2.7, gmail

For users of our Django app that receive their emails through gmail they are finding that emails are getting grouped into conversations that shouldn't be.

I'm not sure what gmail expects in an email to consider it unique enough to not group as a conversation but when I send plain text emails with DIFFERENT subjects using `send_mail` or even try a multipart/alternative with `EmailMultiAlternatives` with an html body gmail still assumes they are part of the same conversation.

Obviously this creates confusion when our application sends emails with different subjects and bodies to the same user and they are all grouped and gmail only shows the subject of the first message in the conversation.

I have 100% confirmed by looking at the raw original email messages to make sure the emails are different subjects and bodies.

I just want to know if I can change anything in how django creates the email message so it can play nice with gmail conversations.

I am using python 2.7.4, and can replicate the "issue" with Django 1.4 and 1.5.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is anything you can do with your messages to 'force' gmail to do as you want. The only way may be to make sure messages on different subjects have a different 'From' email address

Comment: Hey that actually worked.  I just changed the "noreply@..." to "noreply+randomnumber" and it's forcing to different threads.

Comment: Nice, i'll add it as an answer for you to accept then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure messages on different subjects have a different 'From' address